# Exporting PDUs from pcap in linux machine

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tshark

I want to extract all the PDUs from a pcap on linux machine.
I have a windows system with 64-bit processing, which has wireshark installed on it. The wireshark provides a option of exporting PDUs as

```
File -> Export PDUs to file
```

This pop ups a new window that need how you want to export the PDUs.
[image: Pop up window looks like this.]
Select OSI layer 3 and click OK. This gives me the desired PDUs from the pcap.

I want to achieve this on a linux machine using tshark/wireshark or any other software. I have tried through tshark, but not able to achieve this till now.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to achieve this on a linux machine using tshark/wireshark

Step 1: Make sure you have Wireshark 1.12 or later on your Linux machine.

Step 2: Run Wireshark on the file.

Step 3: Select "Export PDUs to file" from the "File" menu.

Step 4: Select OSI layer 3 in the dialog it pops up.

Step 5: Click OK.

Comment: Thanks !!.I am able to perform this through GUI interface, but I want to do this through command line.

Comment: "I want to do this through command line" That's not supported; there's no way to do that in tshark.